# Vuetable transform function does not work

Tags: vue.js, pagination, vue-tables-2

I am using vuetable-2 library for tables.
I 've already seen this [page](https://www.vuetable.com/guide/data-transformation.html) and it didn't helped me.
I use single file components. The transform() function does not work. Here is the code:

```
// SomeComponent.vue
<script>
methods: {
    transform(data) {
      console.log('transform()')
      return data
    }
}
</script>

<template>
    <vuetable ref="vuetable" :api-url="'...'" fields="..." :transform="transform"></vuetable>
</template>
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

You might have missed the colon before transform props. Or try changing the function's name from transform to transformMethod

```
:transform="transform"
```

Comment: It was a typo. I use properly the colon in the props, like you said :transform="...". I 've changed the name, but with no result. :(

Comment: Do you receive data back from the API endpoint properly? Is the API endpoint working? Do you find any error on the console? and also check if Vue event is firing from the vue dev tools on your browser, then please share it

Comment: Thank you. All these are OK.